# Ayuda con arrays y laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

tengo un problema no logro pasar datos desde mi DB a mi array

```
public function index(){
  $categories = Category::where('slug', 3)->first();
    return view('store.category-detail')->with([
    'subcategories'=>'1'->subcategories,
    'categorySlug'=>$slug, 
    'titlePage'=>$categories->name]);
}
```

el problema esta en:

```
'subcategories'=>'1,2'->subcategories,
```

[image: Esta es mi tabla de subcategorias]

el problema es como paso los ID de forma correcta por array?

Comment: Hola, intento hacer que se muestren las sub categorías de una determinada categoría madre ID=3

Comment: ¿Y tienes definida la relación entra la categoría y las subcategorías en los modelos?

Comment: Si están relacionadas con la clave foránea

Comment: Lo que busco aquí es anular Las categorías madres y solo mostrar las sub categorías sin que nadie tenga que entrar mediante la ruta de la categoría madre, para eso quise hacerlo de esta forma, ya definiendo la id de las sub categorías

Comment: Subcategory, en el modelo también lo relacioné con category(madre)

Comment: Para obtener las subcategorías donde la categoría "madre" tenga `id=3`, puedes hacer la consulta sobre el modelo Subcategory `$subcategories = Subcategory::where('category_id', '=', 3)->get();`

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que quieres obtener son las subcategorias, pero no que da claros los datos de partida, por lo que veremos tres formas diferentes de hacerlo, asumo que existe la relación entre categorías y subcategorías en los modelos:

**Obtener las subcategorías a través de categorías**

```
public function index ()
{
    $categories = Category::where('slug', 3)
        ->with('subcategories')
        ->first();

    return view('store.category-detail')
        ->with('categories', $categories);
}
```

En el ejemplo anterior estamos obteniendo la categoría con `slug` igual a `3` con sus subcategorías relacionadas.

**Obtener categorías con subcategorías filtradas por id**

```
public function index ()
{
    $idSubcategories = [1, 2, 3];

    $categories = Category::where('slug', 3)
        ->with(['subcategories' => función ($query) use ($idSubcategories) {
            $query->whereIn('id', $idSubcategories);
        }])
        ->first();

    return view('store.category-detail')
        ->with('categories', $categories);
}
```

En este caso obtenemos la categoría con `slug` igual a `3` con sus subcategorías relacionadas que coincidan con alguno de los id's pasados `[1, 2, 3]`

**Obtener subcategorías de forma directa por sus id y el id padre**

```
public function index ()
{
    $idSubcategories = [1, 2, 3];
    $subcategories = Subcategory::where('category_id', '=', 3)
        ->whereIn('id', $idSubcategories);
        ->get();

    return view('store.category-detail')
        ->with('subcategories', $subcategories);
}
```

En este caso obtenemos las subcategorías donde `('category_id', '=', 3)` y además el id coincide con alguno de los id's que le indicamos `$idSubcategories = [1, 2, 3];`